# The run.bold returns none if entire content in the table cell is bold

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I am trying to retrieve the contents which are bold and red from MS-word document using python-docx, but if whole content in the table cell is bold and entire paragraph is bold then run.bold returns **None**. 
How do I retrieve the cell formatting details in python-docx.

Here is my code:

```
for table in WordDoc.tables:
for i in xrange(1, len(table.rows)):
    for para in table.rows[i].cells[0].paragraphs:
        for run in para.runs:
            if run.bold:
                print (run.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. `Run.bold` only returns `True` if bold is explicitly applied to that run of text. There can be several other ways that text comes to appear in a bold font. The first would be the run having a character style applied to it. The next could be the paragraph containing it has a paragraph style that includes bold formatting. There are other ways as well, such as a numbering style or table style, but those would be the two most common scenarios.

In any case, `python-docx` doesn't report the "effective boldness" of a run, rather it reports only whether bold is explicitly applied.

Comment: So how can I check whether the entire cell text is bold. I even tried document.xml but couldn't found any <w:b/> tag within <w:tc></w:tc> tag.

Comment: I would suspect a character style, paragraph style, or table style; in that order. Look for a tag with 'style' in its name, maybe `pStyle` or `charStyle`. If you want to dig into it, this page might be a help: http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html

Comment: Also this one and the few that follow it via the 'Next' button on each page: http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/styles/index.html